# Шифрование ссылок

Tags: php

Добрый день. Есть ссылки на видео-файлы, но они не прямые. Как я понял, половина ссылки заисит от пользователя, потому что его данные вбиваются в ссылку.
Помогите расшифровать эту часть ссылки, что там шифруется, и возможно ли вытянуть прямую ссылку на файл?

Пример:

```
{"playlist":[ {"comment":"1 Cезон AniDub","playlist":[ {"comment":"1 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_01_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"2 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_02_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"3 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_03_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"4 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_04_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"5 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_05_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"6 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_06_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"7 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_07_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"8 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_08_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"9 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_09_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"10 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_10_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"11 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_11_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"12 Серия", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_12_720p.flv"}, {"comment":"OVA", "file":"http://37.1.207.27/video/0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_ova_720p.flv"}]} ]}
```

В данном примере шифрованные данные вставляются там, где выделено жирным:

http://37.1.207.27/video/**0a4c819fd2ee7dfa946f9882aa5321a2**/serials/akuma_no_riddle/s01/anidub_akuma_no_riddle_ova_720p.flv

Выделенная часть меняется через какой-то промежуток времени, возможно, это мой айпи.

http://37.1.207.27/player/pl.php?pl=akuma_no_riddle "Лайв демо"

Answer (score 4):

> возможно ли вытянуть прямую ссылку на файл?

Нельзя.
Хеширование - это не шифрование. Расшифровать его нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно (например, если бы это писал я я так бы и сделал) это вообще не шифрование. Для скачивания генерируется случайный ключ (возможно еще и хешируется) и записывается в базу вместе с меткой времени, до которого он действителен. Вместе с ключем может быть записано еще что-нибудь (например IP или User-agent браузера). По прошествии времени жизни ключа он удаляется из базы и ссылка становится недействительной.

Это все делается, чтобы скрывать прямые ссылки на контент, находящийся на сайте. Чтобы пользователи, например смотрели рекламу, перед скачиванием.

Но всё-равно все эти много букв сводятся к соседнему ответу: "Нельзя".

Answer (score 1):

У них там стоит веб сервер nginx, к которому есть хороший модуль [secure link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) – посмотрите примеры, похож на ваш:

> A request of “/p/5e814704a28d9bc1914ff19fa0c4a00a/link” will be internally redirected to “/secure/link”.

Т.е. редирект на сам файл происходит внутри, и снаружи он никак не доступен (если админы не совсем ололо).

Расшифровки **не получится:** в создании ключа (md5 хэша) участвует и внутренний «секрет», и время, и, опционально, IP адрес, и любая другая информация от клиента – версия браузера или GET-параметр.

P.s. но вам ничто не мешает просто выкачать у них весь контент через последнюю ссылку.